# How to add userAdmin user in Mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

How to add a user with [userAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdmin) role in Atlas?

The Cluster Security "Add New User" UI https://cloud.mongodb.com/v2/.....#clusters/security/users shows only limited set of built-in roles without any option to enter role name manually:

[image]

So I am a bit stuck here - there are no options in the UI, and non of the existing roles allow to add users in a shell.

**UPDATE:**

To make it crystal clear I went To "Security" tab in MongoDB Atlas cluster, from there I clicked "Add a new User", clicked "Show advanced options" and got the screenshot above.

**UPDATE 2:**

None of the roles in the list have `userAdmin` privilege.

The most "powerful" [atlasAdmin](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#atlas-user-privileges) covers only:

- readWriteAnyDatabase
- readAnyDatabase
- enableSharding
- dbAdminAnyDatabase
- clusterMonitor

and doesn't have enough privilege to execute `db.createUser()` command.

Comment: I have update my answer. I hope so that it will clarify all your query.

Comment: See the my update answer after the edit statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot grant this role. The **only** way to create new MongoDB users in Atlas is either via the UI or the API. See [Add MongoDB Users](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/) for details and note that this page states:

> Atlas rolls back any user modifications not made through the UI or API. You must use the Atlas UI or API to add, modify, or delete MongoDB users on Atlas clusters.

See [Create a Database User](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/database-users-create-a-user/) for details on how to create MongoDB users via the API.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I missed this bit in the docs. Apparently even with the API I  can't use any of my custom roles =(

Answer (score 0):

Go To "Security" tab in MongoDB Atlas cluster, from there you can "edit" or "Add a new User".

@Alex Blex, Let's start from Beginning, You want to create the 'user' admin. For what purpose you want to add the user. At "MongoDB Atlas Cluster" there is lists of "Role" Available like

**Roles/Privileges**

```
backup
clusterMonitor
dbAdmin
dbAdminAnyDatabase
enableSharding
read
readAnyDatabase
read
readAnyDatabase
readWrite
readWriteAnyDatabase
```

**Suppose that** you want to create a new "User" with "readWriteAnyDatabase" Role.

Step 1 : First Login to "MongoDB Atlas Cluster" through your User ID & Password Credential.
[image]

Step 2 : After login at first time you shall find the two Tab

> 1. Overview
> 2. Security

Click on the "Security" tab.

[image]

Step 3 : On the Right side above corner you shall find out the button "ADD NEW USER" click on that.

Step 4 : After click on  "ADD NEW USER" , you shall find the screen as mention below.
[image]

Step 5 : Noted Down here, at this screen you decide what you want to do. I mean to say that what kind of User role you want to assigned.

If you shall not select "Show Advanced Options" then three tab

1. Atlas admin
2. Read and write any database
3. Only read any database

Will be available. And according to your requirement you can choose the option and their respective "User ID" and Password.

eg; Like "Atlas Login"

[image]

& "Read and write any database"
[image]

Step 6: If you shall click on "Advanced Roles/Privileges" the you shall find out 
option like
[image]

And the "Advanced Roles/Privileges"
[image]

Select the "Role" according to your requirement and set their "User ID" and "Password".

I hope so that it will help out to you.

> After chat with  @Alex i am creating the "Alex Blex" User with
>   "dbAdmin" role for "AlexBlexDatabase".

See the screen shot below

[image]

Comment: Thanks, apparently the question is not clear enough that the screenshot was taken exactly from this page. There is still no option to add user with userAdmin role.

Comment: @Alex Blex, What "Role" you want to That user "atlasAdmin" Or "readWriteAnyDatabase".

Comment: No sir, I want [userAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdmin) role. Really appreciate your efforts, but it doesn't answer the question. I have updated it again to elaborate why I need this particular role. `root` or any other that  includes user management privileges would work as well.

Comment: Sorry mate, your *Suppose that you want to create a new "User" with "readWriteAnyDatabase" Role.* is totally wrong assumption, so all the steps after that answer the question I didn't ask. I want to create a user with "userAdmin" role, not "readWriteAnyDatabase".

Comment: @Alex Blex, You just select the "dbAdmin" Role from the "Advanced Roles/Privileges" menu options. And as per your desire select "user id" and "password". For example i have shown  "readWriteAnyDatabase" role and created in my "MongoDB Atlas Cluster".

Comment: Already did it. dbAdmin can't create new users. Nor any other role from the list.

Comment: If you didn't notice, your last screenshot is the one I posted in the question. Your last sentence *Select the "Role" according to your requirement and set their "User ID" and "Password".* is exactly where I got stuck - there is no Role in the list that matches my requirement, and my question is how to work it around.

Comment: @Alex Blex, During Creation of "Atlas Cluster" sandbox. whatever you have given "user Id" and "Password". That is your "atlasAdmin@admin". Through which id you can able to update any role.

Comment: Dear Md Haidar Ali Khan, Thanks for all the efforts you put into it. The "Update 2" I made couple of hours ago explicitly says that "atlasAdmin" Role is not sufficient. It does not allow to execute `db.creareUser()` command, nor any other commands that require `userAdmin` privileges.

Comment: @Alex Blex, I am sure during "dbAdmin" new user creation you are not mentioning any "database" name in the "Atlas Cluster" . Until unless you shall not mention the "database name" then "dbAdmin"  new user will not create.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, but I fail to comprehend the last comment. Of course I name the db when I create a user in specific db. I have no problems to create users in the Atlas UI using the roles provided in the drop-down list.

Comment: @Alex Blex, See the my answer , after edit statement i have created one user with your name and also assigned the databse with "dbAdmin" Role.

Comment: Thanks man, I created dbAdmins myself, and it works like a charm. Just to explain what the problem is - can you use these credentials to connect to the cluster in mongo shell, and execute `db.creareUser({user:"test18", pwd:"asdadasd", roles: ["read"]})` command ? I can't. It results with `Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command { createUser:....` error.

Comment: @AlexBlex,Welcome. can you use these credentials to connect to the cluster in mongo shell, and execute . For that you have to asked the next question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry, but it is exactly the point of this question - none of the roles provided in the list allow to execute such command.