# How do you create an atlas user in a non-admin db?

Tags: mongodb, users, mongodb-atlas

There doesn't seem to be an option in mongo atlas UI to create a user in any database other than admin.

Comment: Is the question here, "how do I create a mongo atlas user with an `authSource` other than `admin`?" That's the question that led me here, but the only answer so far doesn't seem to address it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create new MongoDB users in Atlas is either via the UI or the API.

Have a look at [this answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/192593/22336) to find out more.